# transformRequest not working in angularjs 1.2.21

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making api call method using $http.

I want to do some changes in request before service call.Hence, I am using `transformRequest` in config of $http.
But this call is not working if I am using `transformRequest` or `transformResponse` in $http config.

Without `transformRequest` or `transformResponse` api call is working fine.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http({
        method: type,
        url: url,
        params: null,
        data: data,
        headers: null,
        transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter) {
            console.log('transformRequest');
        },
        transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter) {
            console.log('transformRequest');
        },
        cache: false,
        timeout: 120000 // 2 Min
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.reject(data);
    });
return deferred.promise;
```

My current version of angularjs is **1.2.21**

Comment: The transformRequest and tranformResponse should return something, currently there is only console.log. Can you show what you have implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to return data from `transformRequest` & `transformResponse` .

Updated code :

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({
            method: type,
            url: url,
            params: null,
            data: data,
            headers: null,
            transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter) {
                console.log('transformRequest');
                // Do transformRequest stuff here
                return angular.toJson(data);
            },
            transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter) {
                console.log('transformRequest');
                // Do transformResponse stuff here
                return angular.fromJson(data);
            },
            cache: false,
            timeout: 120000 // 2 Min
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject(data);
        });
    return deferred.promise;
```